# android aapt version 25 fails on Ubuntu

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

android gradlew assemble keeps failing with the following error:

> /home/foreman/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: 3:  /home/foreman/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.0/aapt: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

current buildToolsVersion is 25.

When downgrading to 24.x - same issue.

When downgrading to 23.x - works perfectly.

Downgrading to 23.x is currently not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it covered. for everyone facing this issue:
my ubuntu is 32bit version. Android stopped supporting 32bit architecture since 24.0.0. So aapt just couldn't be executed.

Would be lovely though if the error message were less generic :(

Comment: Hey @SemyonM, I'm experiencing the same problem also. Did the 64-bit Linux fix this problem?

Comment: Absolutely yes.